# How to implement shareing in cocos2d-x

Tags: iphone, facebook, gmail, cocos2d-x, share

I am new cocos2dx developer.I am using the version cocos2dx 2.2.6.Now i want to share image on gmail and facebook.I refer many site and suggestion but still i am not clear about sharing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `UIActivityViewController` to create a sharing dialog and use some `CCRenderTexture` code to take a screenshot. When the share button is tapped, a number of options for sharing are available depending on what applications the user has available on their phone.

---

You can create a sharing popup using the following code:

```
func openShareDialog() {
    var scene = CCDirector.sharedDirector().runningScene
    var node: AnyObject = scene.children[0]
    var screenshot = screenShotWithStartNode(node as! CCNode)

    let sharedText = "Text"
    let itemsToShare = [screenshot, sharedText]

    var excludedActivities = [ UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo]

    var controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then we can take a screenshot using a `CCRenderTexture`:

```
func takeScreenshotWithNode(node: CCNode) -> UIImage {
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().nextDeltaTimeZero = true
    var viewSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().viewSize()
    var rtx = CCRenderTexture(width: Int32(viewSize.width), height: Int32(viewSize.height))
    rtx.begin()
    node.visit()
    rtx.end()
    return rtx.getUIImage()
}
```

---

Here's an example of what the popup would actually look like when displayed:

[image: Example UIActivityViewController]

You can find more information on the `UIActivityViewController` in [Apple's docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/)

Comment: thanks for helping me  but i using the cocos2dx ,so is this code is allow in cocos2dx  or not??

Comment: i try to implement this code but some of the keyword is not allowed in cocoss2dx.

Comment: Can you copy / paste the error you're getting? @Amishabeladiya

Comment: when  implement your first code in that var and let keyword is not support in cocos2dx so that any  other solution for that.

Comment: @Amishabeladiya: what programming language are you trying to use? This code is for Swift

Comment: I using the c++ for cocos2dx.

Comment: This code is written in Swift for cocos2d-objc, so it won't work. Since you're programming for the iPhone, it would be easier to use Objective-C (which wouldn't be too hard since you seem to know C++ already) or Swift than C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can might find it handy to start by reading the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/cocos2d-x#cocos2dx).

There are additional [detailed instructions](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/facebook-sdk/en) in the cocos2d-x.org site including ones for [iOS](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/facebook-sdk/facebook-sdk-on-ios/en).

Comment: I do in my project above the link suggestion  but the sharing screen is not show.It is blank nothing change in project.

Comment: and this instruction is for cocos2dx-js .But now i use the cocos2dx c++.Any other suggestion for sharing in cocos2dx c++.